# Why is the combination of hydrated aluminium oxide and magnesium hydroxide used to treat heartburn?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, ph

> Why is the combination of hydrated aluminium oxide and magnesium hydroxide used to treat heartburn?

I get why $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ would be used since its a strong base and is badly soluble in water. Thus it won't do harm to the oesophagus in comparison to something like $\ce{NaOH}$. Aluminium oxide is also poorly soluble, however it is a weak base so what is the point of combining this substance with magnesium hydroxide instead of just increasing the dose of magnesium hydroxide?

Comment: Different antacids (used to treat heartburn) have different chemical constitutions - see [this table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antacid#Some_well-known_antacid_brands). As to why someone would choose one over the other, I admittedly have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydrated $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$, aka *milk of magnesia*, is an [osmotic (saline) laxative](http://www.lbma.org.uk/assets/blog/alchemist_articles/Alch47Stokes.pdf), as well as antacid.

$\ce{Al(OH)3}$ is also an antacid, but has the opposite effect on the bowels: [it's costive, i.e. a binding agent](http://www.drugs.com/sfx/aluminum-hydroxide-side-effects.html). [Aluminum has also been linked (with much uncertainty!) with Alzheimer's disease](http://www.webmd.com/alzheimers/guide/controversial-claims-risk-factors), so it has become less popular as an antacid.

The combined effects of $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ as laxative and $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ as a costive might tend to counteract each other, so as to avoid interfering with colonic function.

However, it would be far simpler [to use $\ce{CaCO3}$ as an antacid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_carbonate#Health_and_dietary_applications), unless the release of $\ce{CO2}$ bubbles or excess calcium in the diet is an issue.